# If I know that $P(N(B) = k \mid N(W)=n) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, and that $B \subset W$, how can I find $P(N(B) = k)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

If I know that $P(N(B) = k \mid N(W)=n) = {n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}$, where N(B) = number of events in set $B$,  and that $B \subset W$, how can I find $P(N(B) = k)$ by itself? Is it feasible to do?:

$$
P(N(B) = k) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} P(N(B) = k \mid N(W)=n) 
$$

Thanks!

Comment: What do we know about the the probabilities $P(N(W)=i)$?

Comment: The displayed formula is wrong, please use $$P(N(B)=k)=\sum_nP(N(B)=k\mid N(W)=n)P(N(W)=n).$$

Comment: Isn't this your third question displaying basically the same misconception about conditional probabilities?